# How to make JMenuBar activate menu without popping it up?

Tags: java, swing, jmenuitem, jmenubar

I try to make my `JMenuBar` to activate first `JMenu` on `Alt KeyEvent`, but without opening popup, so that one could open popup with arrows keystrokes later. Just like it is done in NetBeans, Mozilla, any other program window.

Here is the code that works not as intended. The worst side effect is that it reacts on alt+tab combination, and it definitely should not popup menu on <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>. I just need to make a menu go to the "armed" state and be able to traverse menus by arrow keys (arrows right & left to "arm" menus and arrow down to open "armed" menu popup). Is there any simple way to make this happen?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Test5 extends JFrame {

    public Test5() {
        super("test");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel pan = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        final JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
        final JMenu menu = new JMenu("File", false);

        menu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);

        JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem("All");
        JMenuItem item2 = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        menu.add(item);
        menu.add(item2);

        JMenu menu1 = new JMenu("Test");
        JMenuItem item1 = new JMenuItem("All");
        menu1.add(item1);

        bar.add(menu);
        bar.add(menu1);

        setJMenuBar(bar);

        setSize(200, 200);
        setVisible(true);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test5();
    }

}
```

**Solved thanks to Guillaume Polet**:
There is some code in  com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel class, wich works with Alt keystrokes:

```
public void initialize() {
    super.initialize();
    // some more initialization here
    KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager()
                        .addKeyEventPostProcessor(WindowsRootPaneUI.altProcessor);
}
```

And the AltProcessor class does all the magic.

If you don't have any custom LaF, you can just use WindowsLookAndFeel as it is, or there is proper example how to process Alt events in menus for your own special LaF.

Comment: take a look, may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657801/focus-on-first-jmenubar-item-on-alt-key-press

Comment: @yggdraa additional question, do you want to highlight programatically or from MouseEvents

Comment: Georgy, i did, and that example acts just like this one - it pops up the menu on alt+tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before starting your GUI, invoke this line:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

And remove the mnemonic.

This will automatically install the desired behaviour on Windows.
If you need this on all platforms, then you will have to go with KeyBindings, but since this behaviour is only observed on Windows, I don't find it problematic to recreate it only on Windows.

Comment: @user714965 no, it does also install appropriate KeyBindings which will reproduce the behaviour seen on Windows, so it is exactly a solution.

Comment: @user714965 Yes, I just did and it works exactly as expected. I took the code of the OP, added that exact line as the first line of the main. Started the code and pressed "ALT" and... "voila"!

Comment: I tried this, nope, looks like Windows, but acts just like acted before

Comment: @yggdraa sorry, forgot that I removed the mnemonic. Make sure to remove it as well

Comment: @user714965 Forgot to tell that you must drop the mnemonic

Comment: Guillaume Polet, got it, this helped
Next step is use this in my custom LaF (since i've got one). Will look into Win32 LaF for answers, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

no idea why, but about answering the question

- 1st step

  1. have to use [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) and with output to the [Swing Action (adviced)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) or [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)
  2. there are two methods `menu.setArmed(true)` or `menu.setSelected(true)`
- but in both cases `JMenu` is selected forever then to required 2nd. step to add [MenuListener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9862855/714968) and restore previous selected or armed to false